# Toggle a text font using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to using ng class ternary operator to toggle class when a check box is selected.

Here is the simple code: http://jsfiddle.net/vqmua1x2/

I am expecting text content to turn bold and unbold when check box is selected.

I am not able to find what is my mistake.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <header>
            <h1>Problems</h1>

    </header>
    <div id="problems">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="val1"/>
                </td>
                <td>prob1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="val2"/> 
                </td>
                <td>prob2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<div>
    <header>
            <h1>Orders</h1>

        <ul>
            <li ng-class="{{val1 }}? 'bold' : 'unbold'">prob1</li>
            <li ng-class="{{val2 }}? 'bold' : 'unbold'">prob2</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
     </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', function ($scope, $rootScope, $window) {
    $scope.val1 = false;
    $scope.val2 = false;   
}]);
```

CSS:

```
.bold {
    font-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.unbold {
    font-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: The first problem with your fiddle is you haven't even bootstrapped Angular correctly, there are errors in the console.  The answer may be something like `ng-class="{bold:val1}"` but I haven't tested.  **Edit:** updated your fiddle, that is the answer. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khtqm7sw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your fiddle is you haven't even bootstrapped Angular correctly, there are errors in the console.

Secondly, check the documentation for `ng-class` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) - your javascript is not correct.

The `ng-class` could look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{bold:val1}">prob1</li>
    <li ng-class="{bold:val2}">prob2</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khtqm7sw/)

Answer (score 2):

- For the fiddle to work, select "no wrap - in body"
- The correct syntax for `ng-class` is:

  ```
  <li ng-class="{ 'bold': val1, 'unbold': !val1 }">prob1</li>
  ```

With these changes the fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/hpwhb62d/

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this.

```
<li ng-class="val1 ? 'bold' : 'unbold'">prob1</li>
```